# How to resolve this Exception: threadWait: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor) execption [haskell]?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am trying to make Client-Server Program using network (version 3.1.1.1) library of Haskell but while  trying to establish connection from client to server I am getting this exception *** Exception: threadWait: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor) and don't know how to resolve this.

code:

```
module PeerToPeer where

import Control.Concurrent (forkFinally)
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import Control.Monad (unless, forever, void)
import qualified Data.ByteString as S
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString (recv, sendAll)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C


runServer :: Maybe HostName -> ServiceName -> (Socket -> IO ()) -> IO ()
runServer mhost port process  = withSocketsDo $ do
    addr <- resolveAddr
    E.bracket (open addr) close loop
        where
          resolveAddr = do
              let hints = defaultHints { addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE], addrSocketType = Stream }
              head <$> getAddrInfo (Just hints) mhost (Just port)

          open addr = do
              sock <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
              setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
              withFdSocket sock $ setCloseOnExecIfNeeded
              bind sock $ addrAddress addr
              listen sock 1024
              return sock

          loop sock = forever $ do
              (clientSocket, clientAddr) <- accept sock
              putStrLn "Connection Established"
              forkFinally (process sock) (const $ gracefulClose sock 5000)


peerHandler sock = do
    msg <- recv sock 1024
    putStrLn ("Incoming :" ++ (show msg))


runClient :: HostName -> ServiceName -> (Socket -> IO a) -> IO a
runClient host port client = withSocketsDo $ do
    addr <- resolve
    E.bracket (open addr) close client

      where
        resolve = do
            let hints =  defaultHints {addrSocketType = Stream}
            head <$> getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just host) (Just port)

        open addr = do
            sock <- socket (addrFamily addr) (addrSocketType addr) (addrProtocol addr)
            connect sock $ addrAddress addr
            return sock


peerComm sock = do
    sendAll sock (C.pack "Hello, world!")
```

Tried this:

```
*Server> runServer Nothing "3000" peerHandler 
Connection Established
*** Exception: threadWait: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)
```

```
*Client> runClient "127.0.0.1" "3000" peerComm
```

Comment: looks like something is going wrong in your `loop` function here:
`forkFinally (process sock) (const $ gracefulClose sock 5000)`?
what's 5000 doing there?

Comment: Closing a socket gracefully. This sends TCP FIN and check if TCP FIN is received from the peer. The second argument is time out to receive TCP FIN in millisecond. In both normal cases and error cases, socket is deallocated finally.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-3.1.1.1/docs/Network-Socket.html#v:gracefulClose